# quick sort problem

Tags: c, qsort

I use qsort from C libary and I have datatype

```
Element_type **pElement and Element_type is struct typedef element_type {int ,char ....}
```

example, and i call quicksor function with

```
qsort(*pElement,iCountElement,(size_t)sizeof(Element_type),compare);
```

and callback function

```
static int compare(const void *p1, const void *p2) {
    Element_type  *a1 = (Element_type  *)p1;
    Element_type *a2 =  (Element_type   *)p2;
    return ( (a2)->iServiceId < (a1)->iServiceId );
}
```

but I always get segmentation fault. Why?

Comment: `qsort` is not required to be a quick sort by the way.

Comment: Are you sorting an array of Element_type* or an array of Element_type ? How have you allocated this array?

Answer (score 3):

Your compare function should return whether elem1 is considered less than, equal to, or greater than elem2 by returning, respectively, a negative value, zero or a positive value.

Also if you want to sort for example an array of `Element_Type` then you would cast the `void*` to type `Element_Type*`.  If your elements that you are trying to sort are `Element_Type*` then you would cast the void* to `Element_Type**`.

If the items you are trying to sort are of type `Element_Type*` the make sure you are allocating memory for each of those items and then initialized for each item before calling qsort.

Comment: think i know that but synthax why segmentation fault my pointer is:
  pElement = (Element_type **)malloc(sizeof(Element_type* )* iNewSize) ;

Comment: @farka: You say you know about the return value but you aren't doing that.

Comment: i have used  pElement = (Element_type **)malloc(sizeof(Element_type* )* iiNewSize) ;
dann :
 
pElement[iCountElement] = (Element_type *)(DMALLOC(sizeof(Element_type))); 
 memset(pElement[iCountElement],"data",sizeof(Element_type));   

after that i call  qsort, but always problem!!11

Comment: @farka: I think the problem is probably in your return value, return 0 when they are the same.  return 1 when elem 1 is greater, and -1 when elem 1 is smaller.

Answer (score 1):

```
   pElement = (Element_type *)malloc(sizeof(Element_type )* iiNewSize);
```

You should call qsort(pElement, ...), not qsort(*pElement, ...).  The pElement declaration at the top of your post cannot be accurate.

Answer (score 0):

```
static int compare(const void *p1, const void *p2) {
    Element_type  *a1 = *(Element_type  *)p1;
    Element_type *a2 =  *(Element_type   *)p2;

    if( (a1)->iServiceId < (a2)->iServiceId )
    {
        return -1; // this means that a1 < a2 in your criteria
    }

    if( (a1)->iServiceId == (a2)->iServiceId )
    {
        return 0; // this means that a1 == a2 in your criteria
    }

    return 1; // this means that a1 > a2 in your criteria
}
```

Call qsort like this:

```
qsort(pElement,iCountElement,(size_t)sizeof(Element_type),compare);
```

**LATER EDIT:** give us a piece of code so we can see more problems if that's the case

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest way to correct your compare function:

```
 static int compare(const void *p1, const void *p2) {
    Element_type  *a1 = (Element_type  *)p1;
    Element_type *a2 =  (Element_type   *)p2;
-   return ((a2)->iServiceId < (a1)->iServiceId );
+   return (a1->iServiceId) - (a2->iServiceId);
 }
```

I can't read the first code segment, so I won't make suggestions on your segfault.